# how to get image real size from ALAssetsLibrary ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to select all real size images from ALAssetsLibrary and save in document folder. Here is my code to get real size image from ALAssetsLibrary.I get the following error.Is there any other way to get real size image from ALAssetsLibrary?

> Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died

```
-(void)test{

    for (int i= 0; i < chosenImagesArray.count; i++) {
            NSDictionary *chosenImage = [self.chosenImages objectAtIndex:i];
                ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
                [assetLibrary assetForURL:[chosenImage valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
                 {
                     ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];

                     unsigned long imageDataSize = (unsigned long)[rep size];
                     imageDataBytes = malloc(imageDataSize);
                     [rep getBytes:imageDataBytes fromOffset:0 length:imageDataSize error:nil];
                     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:imageDataBytes length:imageDataSize freeWhenDone:YES];
                     UIImage *myImg =[UIImage imageWithData:data];

                     //Crop to Standard Size
                     UIImage *readyToWriteImage = [self croppIngimageByImageName:[self fixrotation:myImg ] ];
                     //Write To Document Directory
                     [self writeChosenImage:readyToWriteImage];




                 }
                 failureBlock:^(NSError *err) {
                                  NSLog(@"Error: %@",[err localizedDescription]);

                                 return ;
                  }];

            }

}
```

Comment: you can get size of uiimage with its size property like this image.size

Comment: Thank you. But I need to get image with size (2448 × 3264) .Not only size.

Comment: You can follow this tutorial "How to get meta data of an Image" as size is in the metadata of image so you can get size from returned dictionary of meta data this is the link http://blog.codecropper.com/2011/05/getting-metadata-from-images-on-ios/

Comment: you can do this UIImage *myImg =[UIImage imageWithData:data];   and then myImg.size it will give you original image size which you picked from library

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas I will try the tutorial.Thank you!

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas ,how could I convert metadata to NsData ,please? Thank you

Comment: you can get metadata in the form of NSDictionary so no need to convert just print it and get size NSDictionary *metadata = asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata;//asset is ALasset

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas yes I get metadata .And The for UIImage *myImg =[UIImage imageWithData:data]; How can I convert metadata to data?

Comment: meta data is some thing else than data. here you are getting image from NSdata.its not a metadata the tutorial I have given you thoroughly expalin the thing you needed Kindly go through it again Did you only want to get image with its size ? if yes then you can get from myImg.size it will gice you size of that image

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial "How to get meta data of an Image" as size is in the metadata of image so you can get size from returned dictionary of meta data this is the link http://blog.codecropper.com/2011/05/getting-metadata-from-images-on-ios/

thanks